# Getting Security error while setting up the maven project - java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException

Tags: java, maven-3, java-security

I'm new to maven and setting up maven for the first time. I'm getting following error with Java and hitting mvn install command.

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (ht
tps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clea
n-plugin-2.5.pom: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non
-empty -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better than a straight answer here ...
[make a settings.xml in a hidden folder in your home for Maven](https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2018/03/resolving-maven-trustanchors-parameter.html)